# Webpack ejs loader with img balises

Tags: webpack

I use **Webpack 4** and the **ejs-loader** to genrate my **.html**, like this I can includes ejs files (contains html) and seperate my code.

The problem is that I want to include  balizes in my ejs code and apparently the **ejs-loader doesn't support the url-loader** (or file-loader) to generate my image in the destination path.

This is my webpack rules (I have **html-loader** because **I thought that the html-loader was applied after the ejs-loader**, and like this, the img balize generate my image, but this doesn't work) :

```
    {
      test: /\.ejs$/,
      loader: 'ejs-loader'
    },

    {
      test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
          options: { 
            limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
            name: devMode ? 'images/[name].[ext]' : 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
        } 
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.(html)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          attrs: [':data-src']
        }
      }
    }
```

Have you any suggestions please, I don't find the same case on the Internet.

thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution (alternative) for me

I maked an `api` (php) who returns the image, like that I can source the `<img>` with the api.